# Tuleap Appliance

Tags: installation, virtual-machine, appliance

Just install the Tuleap appliance.  I was able to run the setup using the VM IP address. However I am not able to log onto the main landing page.  When type the ip address in the browser (FF,Chrome or IE) I am not getting the main page come up.
Any ideas.
The appliance is installed under virtualbox and I can log on the VM machine via default terminal logon.

Answer (score 0):

Hi chekc out your virtual box Network card settings. i think you have to select the option "Use HOST NETwork Card" in virtual box settings.

Comment: More details on why you think this solves the problem would be helpful.